# How do I make a singular fetch request in Javascript with ReactJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, fetch-api

I'm trying to create a simple React website where when I press a button, it sends a GET request to my nodeJS server. I'm using the fetch API to make the GET request. The problem is that when I press the button on the front-end website, it sends multiple GET requests to my node server.

Here is my react code:

```
import { Stack, Button } from '@mui/material';
import './App.css';

function On(){
  fetch("192.168.1.23:5000/on");
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
    <div className='App-div'>
      <header className="App-header">
          <Stack spacing={2}>
            <Button onClick={On} size="large" variant='contained'>Send</Button>
          </Stack>
      </header>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}



export default App;
```

Here is my Server code:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.get("/on", (req, res) => {
    console.log("Request");
});

app.listen(5000, () => {console.log("Server Started on Port 
5000")});
```

And here is an image of my server's console after one GET request:

[image: Image of Console]

As you'll notice, it says "request" three times instead of just one. It does this consistently. One button press equals three GET requests.

Any help on this problem would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Add the "On" function into a useEffect

Comment: I don't trust your debugging and assumptions about what's happening. Provide a more complete example.

Comment: What do you mean by a more complete example? @super

Comment: @devpolo adding function into a useEffect is unnecessary in this case, as it's invokation is not part of the render cycle, but rather of the buttons click event

Comment: I mean that all we see is some random console log that says `Request` three times. And we are to assume you have not made any more mistakes or incorrect assumptions about the code along the way? You can show your backend code. You could log the actual request path to verify it's the once you expect. You can check the devtools of your client to see if it's also saying it sends 3 every time you press the button etc. As far as I can tell, you have checked nothing and then made assumptions.

Comment: I just added the server code. @super

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your frontend code looks fine to me, but to verify you can check your network tab inside your browser to see if multiple requests are being sent. If not, then this is a problem with your webserver and not your client code.

Edit: Nevermind... your On function should be declared inside your App component. Move it there like this

```
import { Stack, Button } from '@mui/material';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  function On(){
     fetch("192.168.1.23:5000/on");
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
    <div className='App-div'>
      <header className="App-header">
          <Stack spacing={2}>
            <Button onClick={On} size="large" variant='contained'>Send</Button>
          </Stack>
      </header>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}


export default App;
```

Comment: Three requests are being send since there is three "Request" logs.

Comment: That conclusion seems logical, however I can certainly have my node server log "Request" three times on a single request...

Comment: When I move the "On" function into the "App" function everything is really delayed. And it still says "request" three times. @Egge

Comment: Please see this example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-wgfu2k?file=App.tsx

As you see this code works as expected

Comment: I tried this code and accessed the website from and different device, and then it only sends one GET request. @Egge

Answer (score 0):

You can add a submitbtndisabled feature to prevent multiple API calls.
Something like this:

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { Stack, Button } from '@mui/material';
import './App.css';

function On() {
  const [isDisabled, setIsDisabled] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setIsDisabled(true);

    fetch("http://192.168.1.23:5000/on")
      .then(() => {
        setIsDisabled(false);
      });
  }

  return (
    <Button
      onClick={handleClick}
      disabled={isDisabled}
      size="large"
      variant="contained"
    >
      Send
    </Button>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="App-div">
        <header className="App-header">
          <Stack spacing={2}>
            <On />
          </Stack>
        </header>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Why would you do that? If your click-handler fires multiple times on a single click, something else must be wrong. Also useState can only be used in functions and hooks. Also useState would cause an unnecessary rerender.

Comment: It still sent three GET requests. @amisha

Comment: Yesterday,I was facing the same issue but in Firebase and added the disabled button to prevent multiple calls at the same time, which was working fine for me.